# Getting Mac OS X version without using Carbon

Tags: macos

I need to get the 'nice' Mac OS X version string (e.g., "10.5.8").  [Other sources](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DeterminingOSVersion) say to use the "gestalt" to reliably get this value.  The problem is, the Gestalt is a Carbon API and I can't link to Carbon (its a long story).  Is there some other way, perhaps a direct Cocoa method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]
```

Comment: That property gives you a string like "Version 10.9.1 (Build 13B42)", not a plain version number. The header comments also state that that string is localized and should not be used for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can run sw_vers in an NSTask and sort through its output.